# In Linux, how can I find which running programs have their executable file deleted?

Tags: linux, process

On my server I see a running process in the list generated by `ps aux`. With these options `ps` shows the full command.

Checking the command learns that the executable file has been deleted.

Is there an easy way to find all such processes?

Answer (score 2):

If your `find` supports `-ls` and there is some deleted exectutable running, then this command

```
sudo find /proc -name exe ! -path "*/task/*" -ls 2>/dev/null | grep ' (deleted)$'
```

will probably generate a line that ends like this example:

```
… /proc/9956/exe -> /path/to/executable\ (deleted)
```

This means the process with PID `9956` is executing `/path/to/executable` which is now deleted.

Notes:

- `-ls` is not required by POSIX. Your `find` may not support it or it may support it but generate output in a different format.
- An existing running executable named `anything (deleted)` will generate a false positive.